# How to get value from checkbox and post array in codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, checkbox, codeigniter-3

How to get value form multiples checkbox and post array in codeigniter? I have problem when I get value post array and echo the value. I see only the value of the last checked checkbox. How to show post value when submit?
You find three files: view, Controller and Model. Please check where I wrong...

UPDATE.PHP:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<?php echo form_open('page_controller/update_page_post'); ?>

<div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                    <label><?php echo trans('subcategory'); ?></label>
                </div>
           </div><div class="col-xm-12">
                         <div class="table-responsive">
                             <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" role="grid">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                <?php   $valuesub = ($page->subcat_recip_id); ?>
                            <?php   $array_of_values = explode(",", $valuesub); 
                                //if ($item['parent_id'] != "0" && $item['subcat_recip_id'] == "0") :
                    foreach ($array_of_values as $item) { 

                        if(in_array($subcat_recip_id,$item)): {  ?>

                       <td>
                           <input type="checkbox" name="subcat_recip_id[]" class="square-purple" value="<?php echo html_escape($item["title"]); ?>" CHECKED> &nbsp; <?php echo html_escape($item["title"]);
                                    } ?>
                                <?php   else: { ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="subcat_recip_id[]" class="square-purple" value="<?php echo html_escape($item["title"]); ?>"> &nbsp; <?php echo html_escape($item["title"]);
                        } 

                                endif;  }?>
                                </td> 
        <?php echo html_escape($valuesub); ?></tr>
                                 </tbody>
                             </table>
                 </div>   
                </div>
        </div>
```

PAGE_MODEL.PHP:

```
<?php class Page_model extends CI_Model
{
public function input_values()
{
    $data = array(
        'lang_id' => $this->input->post('lang_id', true),
        'title' => $this->input->post('title', true),
        'slug' => $this->input->post('slug', true),
        'page_description' => $this->input->post('page_description', true),
        'page_keywords' => $this->input->post('page_keywords', true),
        'page_content' => $this->input->post('page_content', false),
        'parent_id' => $this->input->post('parent_id', true),
        'page_active' => $this->input->post('page_active', true),
        'title_active' => $this->input->post('title_active', true),
        'breadcrumb_active' => $this->input->post('breadcrumb_active', true),
        'need_auth' => $this->input->post('need_auth', true),
        'howmany_people' => $this->input->post('howmany_people', true),
        'difficulty' => $this->input->post('difficulty', true),
        'howmany_time' => $this->input->post('howmany_time', true),
        'location' => $this->input->post('location', true),
        'subcat_recip_id' => $this->input->post('subcat_recip_id')
    for ($i=0; $i<count($menu_links); $i++) 
   {
    echo $subcat_recip_id[$i];
   } 
    );  
    return $data;
}
//add page
public function add()
{
    $data = $this->page_model->input_values();
    if (empty($data["slug"])) 
    {
    //slug for title
    $data["slug"] = str_slug($data["title"]);
    if (empty($data["slug"])) 
      {
            $data["slug"] = "page-" . uniqid();
      }
    }
    return $this->db->insert('pages', $data);
}

//update page
public function update($id)
{
    //set values
    $data = $this->page_model->input_values();
    if (empty($data["slug"])) {
        //slug for title
        $data["slug"] = str_slug($data["title"]);
        if (empty($data["slug"])) {
            $data["slug"] = "page-" . uniqid();
        }
    }
  $page = $this->get_page_by_id($id);
  if (!empty($page))  {
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    return $this->db->update('pages', $data);
}
     return false;
}
```

PAGE_CONTROLLER.PHP

```
 * Add Page Post*/
public function add_page_post()
{
    //validate inputs
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', trans("title"), 'required|xss_clean|max_length[500]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === false) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('errors', validation_errors());
        $this->session->set_flashdata('form_data', $this->page_model->input_values());
        redirect($this->agent->referrer());
    } else {

        if (!$this->page_model->check_page_name()) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('form_data', $this->page_model->input_values());
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', trans("msg_page_slug_error"));
            redirect($this->agent->referrer());
            exit();
        }

        if ($this->page_model->add()) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', trans("page") . " " . trans("msg_suc_added"));
            redirect($this->agent->referrer());
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('form_data', $this->page_model->input_values());
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', trans("msg_error"));
            redirect($this->agent->referrer());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Theres not enough info here for us to help you I'm afraid. For example we don't know what $menu_links is like, and we don't know how you are processing the $_POSTed data. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this code
in your Page_model put this code.

```
public function input_values(){
$checkbox = implode(',', $this->checkBox());
$data = array(
    'lang_id' => $this->input->post('lang_id', true),
    'title' => $this->input->post('title', true),
    'slug' => $this->input->post('slug', true),
    'page_description' => $this->input->post('page_description', true),
    'page_keywords' => $this->input->post('page_keywords', true),
    'page_content' => $this->input->post('page_content', false),
    'parent_id' => $this->input->post('parent_id', true),
    'page_active' => $this->input->post('page_active', true),
    'title_active' => $this->input->post('title_active', true),
    'breadcrumb_active' => $this->input->post('breadcrumb_active', true),
    'need_auth' => $this->input->post('need_auth', true),
    'howmany_people' => $this->input->post('howmany_people', true),
    'difficulty' => $this->input->post('difficulty', true),
    'howmany_time' => $this->input->post('howmany_time', true),
    'location' => $this->input->post('location', true),
    'subcat_recip_id' => $checkbox
);
}

public function checkBox(){
$count = count($_POST['subcat_recip_id']);
for($n=0; $n<$count; $n++){
$checkbox[$n] = $_POST['subcat_recip_id'][$n];
}
return $checkbox;
}
```

hopefully it helps

Comment: Now it doesn't add nothing to DB, only NULL fields. Does it need a return $data?

Comment: can you post the result var_dump($data);die;  on input_values(){

var_dump($data);die;
}

Comment: Hip Hura: Where I add var_dump? inside form in view page or inside controller function? Tks

Comment: inside your controller, before close your function, btw did you test another way answer box?

Comment: I updated all files you should need to check where I wrong. TKS

Comment: Here the view of result: https://ibb.co/d5jPXmY  .As you see there's only one value as subcat_recip_id instead of the two selected.

Comment: please chek updated code, i try use implode for combine value of array to variable, chek update code on box answer

Comment: please chek https://github.com/124f5411/git-test/blob/master/combobox.txt

Comment: I just add return $data; to function input_values() and now it works great !! Thanks a LOT.

Comment: Now I update the above code with UPDATE.php page to retrieve the array. As you see I used  explode but I receive Error:Undefined variable: subcat_recip_id. Pls, could you help me again. Thank you.

Comment: please post your code, @Sal can you chek [this](https://github.com/124f5411/git-test/blob/master/combobox.txt)

Comment: Thank you. I opened new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57021641/how-to-retrieve-the-array-values-from-multiples-checkbox . Also you'll find complete code at https://github.com/salvacal/how-to-retrieve-checkbox-value-from-database-in-php-using-explode . Your last code posted works fine, I just added 'return $data;' to the end to function input_values() to ending the function and now its works great. Thank You again. Pls can you check my new post here or at github. Tks

Answer (score 0):

This is what $menu_links is:

```
public function get_menu_links_by_lang()
{
    $lang_id = $this->input->post('lang_id', true);
    if (!empty($lang_id)):
        $menu_links = $this->navigation_model->get_menu_links_by_lang($lang_id);
        foreach ($menu_links as $item):
            if ($item["type"] != "category" && $item["location"] == "header" && $item['parent_id'] == "0"):
                echo ' <option value="' . $item["id"] . '">' . $item["title"] . '</option>';
            endif;
        endforeach;
    endif;
}
```

I edited a code to insert new form page and I need this page to enter some values into DB. All works Ok and they inserted to DB, only the checkbox doesn't work or better it take only the value of the last checked checkbox and not all the checkbox checked! I have tried it in many ways but I can't do it alone. Sorry.